Convert aura:handler to lightning web component
How do I convert this aura attribute and event handler to LWC? I assume when the attribute/property changes, the method runs. but I don't know how to write it in lwc and the docs arent super helpful. Is it getter setter?
I think what i am asking is, how do i subscribe to value changes of an attribute/property in lwc. An example would be helpful
OLD AURA
  <aura:attribute name="displayedData" type="List" default="[]" />
  <aura:handler
    value="{!v.displayedData}"
    name="change"
    action="{!c.handleDisplayedDataChanged}"
  />

NEW JS FILE

    @track displayedData = [];

    handleDisplayedDataChanged() {
        ...do some stuff...
    }


